# How to create a dataframe based on list containing column names?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

**How to create a dataframe based on list containing column names?**

**Situation**

I've got a list of column names stored in variable named data:

- values_c1_114
- values_c1_84
- values_c1_37
- values_c1_126
  ...

In total there are 552 elements in the list data.

Now i want to create a dataframe based on this list of column names.

I thought i could access the values behind the column names by using:

```
for element in data:
    print(element)
```

But this coding only returns the column names and not the values behind the named column.

[Result using for element approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORTzv.png)

It is possible to access the values behind the column names.

[Accessing single column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0LcA.png)

**SOLUTION**:
The following approach solved my problem. The `columns` contains the list of the column names that should be added to the dataframe.

```
data = {k: eval(k) for k in columns}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a sample of your list. the one you are trying to convert I mean.

Comment: you said `data` is a list of column names. where are the values behind them?

Comment: Thanks for your Question. The values are all available when i access them one by one. I've used global variables to create single value lists. Additionally i've created a list containing just the names of the dynamically global created value lists.

Comment: I've just modified my question to provide more details to your question Shireen!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear: Have you created a dataframe or not? If not, then there's no relationship between the two lists. If so, then you need a 2-step iteration: `for col in data.columns: for item in data[col]: print(item)` (ofc with proper indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you need. If I understand OP's question right, OP's key problem is how to get the variable name as a string, then use the set of string as the `dataframe` column.

```py
def namestr(obj, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj][0]
    
import pandas as pd
    
# to simulate the data you have
col1 = [1, 2, 3]
col2 = [4, 5, 6]
data = [col1, col2]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = [namestr(i, globals()) for i in data]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

Or the other way around, you have column names as strings in a list, then you could do something like this:

```
columns = ['col1','col2']
col1 = [1, 2, 3]
col2 = [3, 4, 5]

data = { k: eval(k) for k in columns }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The following approach works perfect:  data = {k: eval(k) for k in columns}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing library
import pandas as pd

# list of column names
data = ['values_c1_114','values_c1_84','values_c1_37','values_c1_126']

# data inside each columns
values_c1_114_list = [i for i in range(1,11)]
values_c1_84_list = [i for i in range(11,21)]
values_c1_37_list = [i for i in range(21,31)]
values_c1_126_list = [i for i in range(31,41)]


# creating dict 
dict = {
    'values_c1_114':values_c1_114_list,
    'values_c1_84':values_c1_84_list,
    'values_c1_37':values_c1_37_list,
    'values_c1_126':values_c1_126_list
}

# creating dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

#printing dataframe
print(df)
```